# Impossible cast from object to short

Tags: c#, object, types, casting, short

I'm facing a problem. A cast from object to short doesn't work.

In a class I have that (juste an exemple) :

```
public const uint message_ID = 110;
```

And in another class, in the constructor, I have that :

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ProtocolTypeManager));

foreach (Type type in asm.GetTypes())
{
      if (type.Namespace == null || !type.Namespace.StartsWith(typeof(MyClass).Namespace))
                continue;

      FieldInfo field = type.GetField("message_ID");

      if (field != null)
      {
           short id = (short)(field.GetValue(type));
           ...
      }
}
```

I have no problem untill the cast. My field isn't null and field.GetValue(type) give me the good object (object value = 110).

Somewhere, I read that the unboxing from object to int work, well, I tried it, but it still doesn't work :

```
object id_object = field.GetValue(type);
int id_int = (int)id_object;
short id = (short)id_object;
```

The exception is this one : http://puu.sh/5d2jR.png (sorry for the French. It says that it's a type or cast error).

Is there anyone who have the solution ?

Thank you,
Veriditas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to unbox it to `uint` (the original type of `message_ID`):

```
object id_object = field.GetValue(type);
uint id_uint = (uint)id_object;
short id = (short)id_uint;
```

Here you can find a very good read about this topic: [Representation and Identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx)

Comment: Ok, I just tried it. The first cast, from object to uint work, the second one don't. And, while correcting, I realize the stupidity I done. This work :

                    object id_object = field.GetValue(type);
                    uint id_uint = (uint)id_object;
                    short id = (short)id_uint;

The second cast concern id_uint and don't id_object... Thank you so much Alberto :)

Comment: The second cast should be `short id = (short)id_uint;` You could also shorten this to `short id = (short)(uint)id_object;`

Comment: Effectively Rory, it's shorter. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The solution above is not working for me, I solved with this:

```
short value1 = Convert.ToInt16(data1["Variable"].ToString());
```